# Creating JWT using without nimbusds library

Tags: java, jwt, token

I am trying to re-write following code (which is using nimbusds library) and on latest version of JAVA.

```
public static String getClientJwtAssertion(String secureKey, PrivateKey privateKey) {
    try {
        Date now = new Date();
        SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT((new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.RS256)).keyID(getThumbprint(secureKey)).build(),
                (new com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet.Builder())
                        .jwtID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        .subject(Constants.CLIENT_ID)
                        .issuer(Constants.CLIENT_ID)
                        .issueTime(new Date())
                        .expirationTime(new Date(now.getTime() + Constants.EXPIRES_IN))
                        .build());
        Set<JWSSignerOption> options = Collections.singleton(AllowWeakRSAKey.getInstance());
        JWSSigner rsaSigner = new RSASSASigner(privateKey, options);
        signedJWT.sign(rsaSigner);
        return signedJWT.serialize();




    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to build same feature using JAVA library and not third party library. I have the code but it's not working and getting error from server regarding authentication.

Here is my code but it's not working. Any pointers will be helpful.

```
public static String signJWTToken(Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privateKey) {
    String header = "{\"alg\":\"RS256\"}";
    String claimTemplate =  "'{'\"jti\": \"{0}\", \"sub\": \"{1}\", \"aud\": \"{2}\", \"iss\": \"{3}\", \"iat\": \"{4}\", \"exp\": \"{5}\"'}'";
    StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
    try {
       token.append(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(header.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
       token.append(".");

       Date now = new Date();
       String[] claimArray = new String[6];
       claimArray[0] = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
       claimArray[1] = Constants.CLIENT_ID;
       claimArray[2] = Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_URI;
       claimArray[3] = Constants.CLIENT_ID;
       claimArray[4] = Long.toString(now.getTime());
       claimArray[5] = Long.toString(now.getTime() + Constants.EXPIRES_IN);

        MessageFormat claims= new MessageFormat(claimTemplate);
        // create payload and add to token
        String payload = claims.format(claimArray);
        token.append(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

        // Sign JWT header
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("AllowWeakRSAKey");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        signature.update(token.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String signedPayload = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString((signature.sign()));

        token.append(".");
        token.append(signedPayload);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        new Throw Exception(e);
    }


    return token.toString();
}
```

The error is as follows ::

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 245 bytes
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:349)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:406)
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2088)
at java.base/java.security.Signature$CipherAdapter.engineSign(Signature.java:1529)
... 4 common frames omitted
```

23:36:59.867 ERROR TokenApplication - Error retrieving access token
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "{"error":"invalid_client","e rror_description":"MSIS9622: Client authentication failed. Please verify the credential provided for client authentication is valid."}"
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101)

Comment: Which provider in your Java code (which you claim does not use third-party libraries) is supposed to support the `AllowWeakRSAKey` algorithm? The [JCA/JCE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-F41EE1C9-DD6A-4BAB-8979-EB7654094029) providers do not have one (at least as far as I know). When I run the code I get a *NoSuchAlgorithmException: AllowWeakRSAKey Signature not available* exception. The analog to `RS256` is `SHA256withRSA`, with which your code generates a valid signed JWT, as can be checked e.g. on jwt.io.

Comment: import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.opts.AllowWeakRSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;

Comment: I refer to the line `Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("AllowWeakRSAKey")` in the second code snippet. Even with the two imports from your last comment and the nimbus-jose-jwt.jar, a *NoSuchAlgorithmException: AllowWeakRSAKey Signature not available* is thrown showing that `AllowWeakRSAKey` is not supported. In contrast, the exception you posted is not reproducible on my machine. As already mentioned, try `SHA256withRSA` as algorithm, s. [The SunRsaSign Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-17E3589E-E4BA-4881-9B12-9880DD2D128D).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Appreciate the help. I tried to replace the AllowWeakRSAKey with SHA256withRSA for the Signature Signatue = Signature.getInstance("AllowWeakRSAKey) part and getting "invalid credentials error" . by the way Here are all the imports. ........
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSAlgorithm; and JWSHeader and JWSSigner;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSSignerOption;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSASSASigner;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.opts.AllowWeakRSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, see here online: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/OAN. The token signed with the code (using `SHA256withRSA`) can be successfully verified with the exported public key on https://jwt.io/ (choose *RS256* as algorithm on jwt.io).

Comment: When i set it to SHA256withRSA, it's not working for me. So, even though it might be correct the ( second party with I am sending token ) is invalidating it.  I will keep you updated on this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> RSA is only able to encrypt data to a maximum amount equal to your key
> size (2048 bits = 256 bytes), minus any padding and header data (11
> bytes for padding).

So the number of maximum bytes:

```
max bytes = (key length in bits / 8 ) - 11
```

As a result, it is often not possible to encrypt files with `RSA` directly. If you want to encrypt more data, you can do something like:

1. Generate a 256-bit random key.
2. Encrypt your data with `AES-CBC` (or any others) with key.
3. Encrypt key with RSA.
4. Send both to other side.

You can also use another key-size, symmetric algorithm and cipher mode. But you should know that `RSA` is not made for the purpose you use it.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the TTL passed was not valid for the library I was using.

After setting it for valid time period I was able to resolve the error.